# Building an array from bottom up

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement

Ok so I am trying to build an array in python from the last row first column, build the last row, and then go up to the second to last row first column and so on.

In other words:

First iteration store data to (n=m=1000 value - x is of 'store_data'):

```
- - - - -
- - - - -
- - - - -
- - - - -
x - - - -
```

next iteration store data to (n=1100, m = 1000 - x is value of 'store_data'):

```
- - - - -
- - - - -
- - - - -
- - - - -
- x - - -
```

6th iteration store data to (n=1000, m = 1100 - x is value of 'store_data'):

```
- - - - -
- - - - -
- - - - -
x - - - -
- - - - -
```

and so on up until (n=2000, m = 2000 - x is value of 'store_data')

```
- - - - x
- - - - -
- - - - -
- - - - -
- - - - -
```

Conditions on where to store

```
n,m = 1000
while(1):    
  if m<2000 and n<2000
                n=n+100
  if m<2000 and n>=2000
                m = m + 100
                n=1000
  if m>=2000 && n>=2000
                m = 1000
                n= 1000
```

So if the first condition is met then I want the value of say the variable 'store_data' in the spot of the first iteration. The if statements are in a while forever loop and store_data gets a new value from a sensor on each iteration of the while loop. So in other words: the array will be 10 x 10 and the last row first column will be the value of 'store_data' when m, n =1000, while the first row last column will be the value of 'store data' when m, n = 2000.

Gosh, I am having a hard time articulating this. But I think it is clear for what I want. What code do I have to add to build this array to my if statements?

EDIT:

Ok I have the following now :

```
n=0 #row of matrix
m=0 #column of matrix
n_iteration = 10
m_iteration = 10
heat_map_reverse = [[0 for x in range(n_iteration)] for x in range(m_iteration)]

while(1): #loop forever
    data = ser.read(4) # look for a character from serial port, will wait up to timeout above.
    if len(data) == 4: #was there a byte to read? should always be true.
        yvals = np.roll(yvals,-1) # shift the values in the array
        yvals[49]=ord(data)
        outFile.write(str(time()-start_time)+" "+str(yvals[49])+"\n") #write to file
        line.set_ydata(yvals) # draw the line
        fig.canvas.draw() # update the Canvas
        win.set_title("Temp: "+str(yvals[49])+" deg C")
    while gtk.events_pending(): #makes sure the GUI updates
        gtk.main_iteration()

    if m<m_iteration and n<n_iteration:
        heat_map_reverse[n][m] = yvals[49]
        n = n + 1
    if m<m_iteration and n>=n_iteration:
        m = m + 1
        n = 0
    if m>=m_iteration and n>=n_iteration:
        m = 0
        n= 0
        break

print heat_map_reverse
```

But it never prints the heat_map_reverse! yvals[49] is the value I want to store in the matrix. Am I not breaking out of the while loop correctly? As it is making the matrix I have a plot of the data coming in - as soon as it is done I want it to break from the while loop and just print the matrix. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not build the list normally and then just reverse it with[`list.reverse()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) or [extended slice notation](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) (`[::-1]`)?

Answer (score 0):

There's a trick you can use that's slightly inefficient, but makes coding this easier.

First, note that the diagonals that you're interested in are described by m - n. That is, all points (m, n) on the same diagonal have the same value of m - n.

If your matrix is 2000 square, then the first diagonal you want has value 1999 [(1999, 0) is on that diagonal], and the last diagonal has value -1999. [(0, 1999) is on that diagonal].

With that insight, the code is relatively simple. Here's some code, including an example of filling a square in the order of iteration.

```
def bottom_up(M):
    for d in xrange(-M + 1, M):
        for n in xrange(M):
            m = n - d
            if m < 0 or m >= M: continue
            yield m, n

square = [['xxx'] * 5 for _ in xrange(5)]
for i, (m, n) in enumerate(bottom_up(5)):
    square[m][n] = '%3d' % i

for line in square:
    print ''.join(line)
```

Once you've got the code working like this, it's just a matter of finding the right range for `n` based on `d` so you don't need the `if` to check bounds:

```
def bottom_up(M):
    for d in xrange(-M + 1, M):
        for n in xrange(max(0, d), min(M, M+d)):
            yield n - d, n
```

Finding these bounds is relatively easy given the original code. You just need to solve n-d=0 and n-d=M, and using max/min to make sure n stays in the range [0, M) too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand what you're trying to do - and i'm also not a very experienced python programmer. But as far as i can tell: Tere is no such thing as an "array" in python.

Python offers various "data types" or "data structures" (...not sure about the terminology) to store data.

If you want to store some values in a 10 by 10 matrix and you want to access them just by index, you can use nested lists. A simple example (three rows, ten columns):

```
matrix = [
    [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109],
    [200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209],
    [300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309]
]
```

You can iterate this matrix in any desired way using corresponding loops. To iterate a list backwards, use `reversed()`:

```
for line in reversed(matrix):
    for column in line:
        print column # or any other command here
```

To build up such nested lists, you can code something that will loop and insert your values backwards as you like - but you can also simply build the list from start to end and use `reversed()` afterwards.

I don't see the need to use values from 1000 to 2000 for iteration, it seems like you only want to store some data "x" in the right place. Why not use simple list indexes, from 0 to whatever length you need?

Plus, it's not possible to store values from 1000 to 2000, step 100, including this numbers - in ten places. You'll need eleven, or you need to exclude the start or end number.

If you really need to stick to that numeric values, use a dictionary instead:

```
matrix = {
    1000 : {
        1000: 'a1',
        1100: 'b1',
        1200: 'c1,
        # etc.          
    },

    1100 : {
        1000: 'a2',
        1100: 'b2',
        1200: 'c2'
        # etc.        
    },        
    # etc.                 
}
```

You could build it and loop through it like this:

```
# build empty matrix
matrix = {}
for line in range(1000, 2100, 100):
    matrix[line] = {}
    for column in range(1000, 2100, 100):
        matrix[line][column] = '' 

# loop that matrix from lines 2000 to 1000, columns from 1000 to 2000:
while True:
    for line in range(2000, 900, -100):
        for column in range(1000, 2100, 100):    
            matrix[line][column] = store_value # do something with the current cell
```

If your values `n` and `m` are provided in the `while()`-loop somehow, you don't need to `for`-loop at all - just access the matrix direclty.